# this.props... is not a function react react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a problem with dispatching a action from componentDidMount...
error is : TypeError: this.props.postDetails is not a function

Action.js

```
export const postDetails = data => ({
        type: "POST_DETAILS",
        post: data
})
```

Container/GetDetails.js

```
import Details from '../components/Details'
import { postDetails } from '../actions'

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ post: state.post });

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({postDetails}, dispatch);

const GetDetails = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps 
)(Details)

export default GetDetails
```

Component/Details.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { postDetails } from '../actions'


class Details extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("did mount details");
        this.props.postDetails();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Details page
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Details;
```

Can someone help me? Why i have this error?

Comment: try console logging your `this.props` and check if you are getting that function in your props

Comment: a get empty object {}

Comment: How does your reducer look like?

Comment: case "POST_DETAILS":
            return[
                ...state.filter(post => post.id == action.id),
                Object.assign({}, action.id)
            ]

Answer (score 1):

In App.js (or wherever you are importing the Details component), are you using the path to your GetDetails *container* (not component)?

I moved state from a component to a container and forgot to update the import path which gave me this same error. Updating the import path to the container took care of it.

Edit:

For example, I have an apiLanding folder that has apiLanding.js (the component) and apiLanding-container.js (the container).

In my app.js, I needed to change

import apiLanding from './components/apiLanding/apiLanding';

to

import apiLanding from './components/apiLanding/apiLanding-container';

That way, the app now has access to the redux state and actions. This was a silly mistake and may not be your issue, but wanted to share just in case the import path was overlooked.

Comment: can you show your code for better understanding? to see the difference in imports.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return an object, where the keys are your props. See [docs](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#inject-todos-todoactioncreators-as-todoactions-and-counteractioncreators-as-counteractions).

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({ postDetails: bindActionCreators({postDetails}, dispatch) })
```

Or, you can use the shorthand notation:

```
const GetDetails = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { postDetails }
)(Details)
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't see bindActionCreator imported. Use eslint to get rid of these errors

Answer (score -1):

There are two things which don't really seem right to me. Personally I never used `bindActionCreators`. I would just create my mapDispatchToProps as following:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    postDetails: () => dispatch(actions.postDetails)
  };
};
```

But also your *postDetails* call expects an argument, which you should add in your function call. So your *mapDispatchToProps* would look like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
      return {
        postDetails: (data) => dispatch(actions.postDetails(data))
      };
    };
```

Also you're importing your action as `postDetails`. Are you sure that this is just one action? And not a combination of all actions in your file? Note how I added your function as `actions.postDetails` instead of just `postDetails`.

Comment: tnx, a fixed this problem, but now i have a problem with reducer :)

Comment: case "POST_DETAILS":
            return [
                ...state.filter(post => post.id !== action.id),
                Object.assign({}, action.id)
            ]

Comment: or something like that : return {
                post:  state.posts.filter( p => p.id !== action.id )
            }